# What do you call someone who helps a volleyball team but isn't playing for the team?

Tags: word-choice

So i'm helping my high schools girl volleyball team and the coach wants to make me part of the team but I obviously don't play for the team since i'm a guy. The coach wants to make a jersey for me as well but I don't know what name I could be called.

Comment: Do NOT pass up the opportunity to be labeled an *athletic supporter.*

Comment: she wants something that has to do with volleyball :(

Comment: You could be their very first [***chorus boy**!*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chorus%20boy) Why should sports teams only usually have *chorus **girls**?*

Comment: It might help if you could describe what you actually do for the team.  Arrange publicity, chase balls, mop the floors, set up the net?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We would be better able to help if you can identify the ways in which you are helping out, and what your locale is. In the U.S., you might be taking the role of a *booster*, a *cheerleader*, a *water boy*, a *pep leader*, and so on.

Comment: Consult the USVBA rules, FIVB rules, or appropriate governing body for who is allowed to be on the floor during a match. You want to be one of those people. You probably want to be an asst. coach.

Answer (score 1):

[Manager](http://theconcordian.org/2016/02/11/student-managers-play-a-key-role-on-sports-teams) or Student Manager or Team Manager.

Your duties as a manager may include:

- Managing the equipment room,
- Washing practice balls/Jersies,
- Preparing equipment for away games,
- Working with the coach for plans for the practice sessions,
- Working with players to make sure they have everything they might need in a practice session or in a game,
- Making sure everything is ready for practice and the games,
- Cheering your teammates on when they are down or when morale is low.

The manager is a very integral and important part of a team. You may not *play* in the games but you are very much a part of the team. You manage the team; you are the glue that holds everything in place. Do it well and take pride in it!